# 2 players Javascript hangman game problem with prompt

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

I am currently making a hangman game, 1st player need to enter a word the player 2 need to guess via a prompt. When i enter the word via the prompt it's in the console log but it's not showing in the page. It is suppose to be show in underslash like: '_ _ _ _ _' depending on the length of the word. How do I get to show the word in underslash form?

Here is what I have so far.

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">


    <title>Hangman</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hangman</h1>
        <div>Wrong Guesses: <span id='mistakes'>0</span> of <span id='maxWrong'></span></div>
        <div>
            <img id='hangmanPic' src="./images/0.jpg" alt="">
            <p>Guess the word:</p>
            <p id="wordSpotlight">The word to be guessed goes here</p>
            <div id="keyboard"></div>
            <button class="btn btn-info" onClick="reset()">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Script:

```
<script>
        let answer = '';
        let maxWrong = 8;
        let mistakes = 0;
        let guessed = [];
        let wordStatus = null;

        function randomWord() {
            var secretWord = prompt("Player 1, enter a word to guess", "");
            secretWord = secretWord.toUpperCase();
            console.log("Word to guess: " + secretWord);

            var secretWordArray = Array.from(secretWord);
            console.log("Word to guess (array): " + secretWordArray);

            var wordArray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < secretWordArray.length; i++) {
                motArray[i] = " _ ";
            }
            return wordArray;
        }

        function generateButtons() {
            let buttonsHTML = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('').map(letter =>
                `<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary m-2" id='` + letter + `'onClick="chooseLetter('` + letter + `')">` + letter + `</button>`).join('');

            document.getElementById('keyboard').innerHTML = buttonsHTML;
        }

        function chooseLetter(chosenLetter) {
            guessed.indexOf(chosenLetter) === -1 ? guessed.push(chosenLetter) : null;
            document.getElementById(chosenLetter).setAttribute('disabled', true);

            if (answer.indexOf(chosenLetter) >= 0) {
                guessedWord();
                checkIfGameWon();
            } else if (answer.indexOf(chosenLetter) === -1) {
                mistakes++;
                updateMistakes();
                checkIfGameLost();
                updateHangmanPicture();
            }
        }

        function updateHangmanPicture() {
            document.getElementById('hangmanPic').src = './images/' + mistakes + '.jpg';
        }

        function checkIfGameWon() {
            if (wordStatus === answer) {
                document.getElementById('keyboard').innerHTML = 'You Won!!!';
            }
        }

        function checkIfGameLost() {
            if (mistakes === maxWrong) {
                document.getElementById('wordSpotlight').innerHTML = 'The answer was: ' + answer;
                document.getElementById('keyboard').innerHTML = 'You Lost!!!';
            }
        }

        function guessedWord() {
            wordStatus = answer.split('').map(letter => (guessed.indexOf(letter) >= 0 ? letter : " _ ")).join('');

            document.getElementById('wordSpotlight').innerHTML = wordStatus;
        }

        function updateMistakes() {
            document.getElementById('mistakes').innerHTML = mistakes;
        }

        function reset() {
            mistakes = 0;
            guessed = [];
            document.getElementById('hangmanPic').src = './images/0.jpg';

            randomWord();
            guessedWord();
            updateMistakes();
            generateButtons();
        }

        document.getElementById('maxWrong').innerHTML = maxWrong;

        randomWord();
        generateButtons();
        guessedWord();
    </script>
```

Comment: Is there a specific question?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev How do I show the secret word on the page in underslash form?

Comment: `Array("word".length).fill(0).map(_ => "_ ").join("").trim();` ?

Answer (score 1):

Using a `for` loop, iterate over the secret word character by character, and check if it's in the `guessed` array. If it is, output the character followed by a space. If not, output an underscore followed by a space.

If there are no guessed letters this will output a row of underscores.

Watch for issues with upper and lower case.

```js
let output = '';
let secret = "secret";
let guessed = ['e', 't'];
for (let char of secret) {
    output += ((guessed.indexOf(char) === -1)?'_':char)+" ";
}
output = output.trim();

console.log(output);  // _ e _ _ e t
```

Comment: It is working, thanks! The underscores appear, but it is not the good number (ex: secret word: 'Hello', it show '_ _ _ _ _ _'). Also, when I click on the right letters of the secret word, they don't show instead of the underscores.

Comment: The code works as shown for different words and different lists of guessed letters. If you want to use it in your program make sure it's using the right variables.

Comment: I'm trying but I can't seems to find how to make it work, sorry I'm new in the coding world.